# PHP header redirect to Wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, header

I want to redirect my validation messages on different pages but it just redirects to the success page but the database remains unchanged.

The else conditions are the problem

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','wordpress'); 

    if(!empty($fullname) && !empty($age) && !empty($email)) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_mypage WHERE email='$email'";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        $data = mysqli_fetch_arrray($result);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO wp_mypage (name, age, email) 
                      VALUES  ('$fullname', '$age', '$email')";
            mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            header("Location: http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=67"); 
        } else {
            header("Location: http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=73"); 
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=73");
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
}
?>
```

Comment: In which file you have kept this code? I think `header` needs to be called before rendering of WordPress template.  Try `init` action hook.

Comment: your header must declare before you render it, just like @Nilambar said.

Comment: if you are using wordpress then don't mix-up wordpress with core queries use word-press standers